# Java - How to make a rectangle spawning method, to spawn multiple rectangles with each different coordinates?

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I am making a simple game using Java, and it works fine.
But I want to have more enemies appearing on the screen than just one.
You will see in my code that I used a x and y variable for the position of the enemy. I would like to have a sort of spawning method, and everytime when you call that method, an enemy will be spawned(so there a multiple enemies).

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Enemy {
static int x = -100;
static int y = -100;

private boolean level2 = false;
private boolean level3 = false;
private boolean level4 = false;
private boolean level5 = false;
private boolean level6 = false;
private boolean level7 = false;
private boolean level8 = false;
private boolean level9 = false;
private boolean level10 = false;
Player player;

public Enemy(Player player) {this.player = player;}

public void update(){
    if(player.getX() < x){
        x -= 2;
    }
    if(player.getX() > x){
        x += 2;
    }
    if(player.getY() > y){
        y += 2;
    }
    if(player.getY() < y){
        y -= 2;
    }       
}

public void scoreMethod(){
    if(GameClass.score == 500){
        level2 = true;
    }
    if(GameClass.score == 1000){
        level3 = true;
    }
    if(GameClass.score == 1500){
        level4 = true;
    }
    if(GameClass.score == 2000){
        level5 = true;
    }
    if(GameClass.score == 2500){
        level6 = true;
    }
    if(GameClass.score == 3000){
        level7 = true;
    }
    if(GameClass.score == 3500){
        level8 = true;
    }
    if(GameClass.score == 4000){
        level9 = true;
    }
    if(GameClass.score == 4500){
        level10 = true;
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20); //THE ACTUAL SPAWNING OF ONE ENEMY
    if(level2)
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20); //HERE SHOULD SPAWN THE SECOND ONE(I TRIED)
    if(level3)
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    if(level4)
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    if(level5)
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    if(level6)
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    if(level7)
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    if(level8)
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    if(level9)
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    if(level10)
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
}
```

}

I am sorry for bad English or unclear question.
Please help me, I have no idea how to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create an enemy "Class" which would be a separate .java file. In this file you would give the enemy rectangles and update method and a drawing method as well as their own appropriate x and y positions. You could then spawn them in with their constructors. I would recommend looking into java "Classes" (not the class that you go to school in, they are just called classes in java). Those will be able to clean up your code and make it easier to make your enemies.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it.I will let you know if it worked or not :)

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to do this would be to make an enemy class.

```
public class enemy {
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
    public static draw(Graphics g) {
        //draw the enemy at xpos and ypos
    }
    public enemy() {
        //this is called the constructor
        //set xpos and ypos to what you want
    }
}
```

Keep an arraylist of enemies, and loop through the list constantly to draw the enemies at the position that is indicated. In this way, you can also change the position of the enemy(make them move around) for cooler game action.

Constructors are like blueprints for classes. Think of a class like an object. The constructor tells java how to make that object.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a main class that you use to play the game, and create the enemies. 
Is there a reason you can just make an arraylist of enemies?
For example, something like this may work to make your game.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Game {
    public Game(){
        playGame();
    }
    private void playGame(){
        //creates 10 enemies
        ArrayList <Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList <Enemy>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            Enemy enemy = new Enemy(player);
            enemies.add(enemy);
        }

    }
}
```